# Make Ahead Quesadillas

Tags: mexican-cuisine

A few friends of mine are visiting and I wanted to make some Quesadillas (No meat). Ordinarily, I would make them, keep them covered in tin foil and serve hot in a few minutes. However, this time, I need to pick up my friends at the airport which would be a ~2 hour return journey. I was wondering at what point should I pause my [recipe](http://allrecipes.com/recipe/farmers-market-vegetarian-quesadillas/) to go pick them up and resume.

I wanted to get as much prepared before hand so I can serve immediately after we return home. If I fry vegetables, tortilla, layer cheese and keep them ready to fry, would that be OK?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that sounds like a great way to do it!

Prepare all of the components ahead of time, assemble the quesadillas, and stash them in the refrigerator.

When you return home with your guests, all you need to do it warm and serve.

The only real consideration is the moisture content of your veggies. You may not want to include them inside the tortilla during the fridge testing period of they are in danger of making the tortilla soggy. It probably won't be an issue, but it's something to consider. You can always cook up the veg and keep them in the fridge separately from the quesadillas until you are ready to heat.

Comment: If you're going to leave them for longer than a couple hours, I might just wait to assemble them to avoid any chance of sogginess in the tortillas. Just prep everything, and throw it between tortillas while the pan's heating.

Comment: Yeah. After reading the recipe there is definitely cause for concern on the sogginess front. I think keeping them separated from the tortillas until you're ready to serve is the best bet.